# Save as in JavaScript - HTML to WORD

Tags: javascript

I'm in trouble with saving a word in Javascript ! I want to save the document as "x" by concatenating several vars.
I tried the following:

```
    <script>// SAVE AS WORD
    var fname = document.getElementsByName("fname")[0].value;
    var name = document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value;
    var company = <?php echo json_encode($company); ?>;
    
   function exportHTML(){
   var header = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' "+
        "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' "+
        "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>"+
        "<head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML to Word Document with JavaScript</title></head><body>";
   var footer = "</body></html>";
   var sourceHTML = header+document.getElementById("pdf").innerHTML+footer;
   
   var source = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(sourceHTML);
   var fileDownload = document.createElement("a");
   document.body.appendChild(fileDownload);
   fileDownload.href = source;
   **fileDownload.download = concat(fname,'-',name,'-LM-',company,'.doc');**
   fileDownload.click();
   document.body.removeChild(fileDownload);
}
</script>
```

The save-as line is the following :

```
   **fileDownload.download = concat(fname,'-',name,'-LM-',company,'.doc');**
```

**Any idea ? Thanks a lot from France !**

Comment: So what's the trouble, exactly? What goes wrong with the code? P.S. this appears to export HTML, so it's not really a Word doc at all. (Word may be able to open it, but giving it a .doc extension and a Word Mime Type is misleading and may even be confusing to Word when it tries to open it.)

Comment: @ADyson the code works perfectly since ".doc" is added in the file-name save as. See below lariuss' answer, it fixed the save as issue I had.

Comment: " since ".doc" is added in the file-name" ...yes I can see that, but that wasn't my point. My point was that while you've given the a file a .doc extension, it's not _really_ a .doc file. It's a HTML file pretending to be a Word doc. While this may work, if Word is tolerant of it, it's generally not good practice to give a file a misleading extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ADyson for your input. I'll run tests on several devices to see if an error occurs. If so, I'll consider switching to another method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`concat` is a method of [`String.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat), so use it like this:

```
fileDownload.download = fname.concat('-', name, '-LM-', company, '.doc')
```

Or you can use the concatenation operator `+` :

```
fileDownload.download = fname + '-' + name + '-LM-' + company + '.doc';
```

Or you can use template strings:

```
fileDownload.download = `${fname}-${name}-LM-${company}.doc`;
```